# JavaServerFaces 2, returning html by ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

```
<h:inputText value="#{finder.valor}" title="Test" id="valor"/>
<h:commandButton value="Search">
    <f:ajax execute="valor" render="output"/>
</h:commandButton>
<br/>
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{finder.find}"/>
```

I wanna do an ajax interactive finder, this finder returns a list of elements (`<li>Element1</li><li>Element2</li>`...)

There is any way to read that htmlTags in the outputText? Because now it appears like plain text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your question is the following:

*How to output HTML-tags with JSF?*

Assuming it is, try this:

```
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{finder.find}" escape="false" />
```

By default JSF will escape all codes. However, you can disable it with `escape="false"`.